# Error: Object of type IntervalStrategy is not JSON serializable when add `indent` to verticalize json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to save a dataclass to a json file and save it, it is ok now without adding paramenter `indent`.

```
class EnhancedJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if dataclasses.is_dataclass(o):
                return dataclasses.asdict(o)
            # return super().default(o)

model_json = json.dumps(model_args, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder)
```

model_args is a dataclass object, take a simple example,

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Model_args:
    x: str
model_args = Model_args(x="bar")
```

However, when I add indent, for example,

```
model_json = json.dumps(model_args, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder,indent=4)
```

it shows

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type IntervalStrategy is not JSON serializable
```

I want to save to json file vertically(make it looks better)

```
 with open("model_args.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(model_json)
```

Comment: `model_json` actually is a str, so add `file_json_new = json.loads(model_json)` before saving

Comment: I have solved this problem by myself, need I close or delete this question?

Comment: you should post your own answer of how you solved it, and then close the question.

Comment: @blueteeth Hi, sorry to bother you, which reason I should choose when closing this question?

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model_json = json.dumps(model_args, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder)
```

model_json is a string format, actually,like `"{x="bar"}"`
if you want to save it as dict and add indent parameter, converting it to dict format firstly by `json.loads()`

```
model_str = json.dumps(model_args, cls=EnhancedJSONEncoder)
model_json = json.loads(model_str)
with open(json_path, "w") as f:
    json.dump(model_json, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your approach using `json.JSONEncoder`, but as a long-term solution, to avoid code bloat when introducing other (more complex) types such as [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types), I would suggest looking into an existing library such as `dataclass-wizard`, which provides built-in support for saving a dataclass instance to a file, e.g. such as with [`JSONFileWizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/wizard_mixins.html#jsonfilewizard):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import JSONFileWizard


@dataclass
class ModelArgs(JSONFileWizard):
    x: str


ma = ModelArgs(x="bar")

## TODO
json_path = './my_file.out.json'

ma.to_json_file(json_path, indent=4)
```

Contents of `my_file.out.json`:

```json
{
    "x": "bar"
}
```

---

*Disclaimer: I am the creator and maintainer of this library.*